# replacing every alternate blank space of a string

Tags: javascript, string

```
var names = "John Keynes
             Carl Gauss
             Paul Feyerabend
             Antoine Lavoisier"
```

Result in output should be :

```
"John Keynes","Carl Gauss","Paul Feyerabend","Antoine Lavoisier"
```

Comment: did you want to add double quotes?

Comment: yea,but the main thing is how to skip alternate spaces

Comment: what's your exact input? I saw more spaces before each name. is there a newline character exists?

Comment: no only spaces exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just capture each two words and match the following one or more spaces. Then replace the whole match with the `$1,`

```
> var names = "John Keynes Carl Gauss Paul Feyerabend Antoine Lavoisier";
undefined
> names.replace(/(\S+\s+\S+)\s+/g, "$1,")
'John Keynes,Carl Gauss,Paul Feyerabend,Antoine Lavoisier'
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters where `\s+` do the opposite of `\S+` which matches one or more space characters. `(..)` called capturing group was used to capture those characters which are matched by the pattern present inside the capturing group. Later we could refer those characters by specifying the group index number on the replacement part.

To enclose the names within double quotes, you need to add another `replace` function.

```
> names.replace(/(\S+\s+\S+)\s+/g, "$1,").replace(/([^,\s]+\s+[^,\s]+)/g, '"$1"')
'"John Keynes","Carl Gauss","Paul Feyerabend","Antoine Lavoisier"'
```

Comment: @ishansoni may i know the reason for unaccepting this answer? It correctly shows the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```js
var names = "John Keynes Carl Gauss Paul Feyerabend Antoine Lavoisier";
alert(names.replace(/(\s+[^s+]*)\s+/g, '$1, '))
```

Comment: but the op's expected output is different.